# Wicket - Update Form after result from callback

Tags: java, wicket

I have a problem when I try to update a form with the result provided by a callback action. This problem is caused by the Wicket singleton thread, and I don't understand how can I implement a solution. 
The code that I need to update is the following.

```
provaButton = new AjaxLink("prova_btn"){
                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget art) {
                    getChannelManagerAPI().getToken(new ChannelManagerCallbackWrapper() {
                        @Override
                        protected void onSuccess(Object object) {
                            Object[] response = null;
                            response = (Object[]) object;
                            for (Object obj : response) {
                                info("Result " + obj.toString());
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                            info("Errore nella chiamata : "+ throwable.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
                    refreshFeedBackPanel(art);
                }

            };
            add(provaButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are making an asynchronous call. Wicket doesn't support suspending the HTTP thread so you have the following options:

1. Block the HTTP thread and wait for a response from the async service. E.g. you can use `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` that `await()` right after the async call and `countDown()` in the callback methods. Use this approach only if you are sure that the async call is fast!
2. Use `org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior` or its specialization `org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior` to do `Long polling`. The idea is that you start the async call and then on every N ms/secs Wicket will make a new Ajax call to check whether there is a response and render it.
3. Use Wicket Native WebSocket to push the result from the async call as soon as it is available.

Comment: Thank you so much. I try to improve one of your suggests.

Comment: I need another help. How can I do for stopping the AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior?

Comment: With, uhm, `#stop(AjaxRequestTarget)`! See https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/c4805d87012c2f0c2e80418453d0c60f3a5db7c7/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior.java#L195